# Gnostice PDF Engine (Delphi) How to create one table following another

Tags: delphi, pdf-generation

I want to create one table of variable length, followed by another table.

You start a new table with

```
TableCols := BeginTable(X, Y, NoOfCols);
```

where X,Y is top left corner of table.

First table may end in middle of first page or extend to subsequent pages.  So I do not know Y of 2nd table.  Is there a CurrentPosition property that will give me Y?  Or a version of BeginTable that does not require X,Y?

Comment: http://www.gnostice.com/support.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cell height before rendering the table and when you have finished rendering the tables, multiply the cell height with the number of rows. Then, you know the height of the current table.

Comment: Doesn't work because some rows contain wrapping text.  I do know how many rows I have but I don't know how tall each row is.  Might be 1, 2, or 3 lines of text tall.

Comment: We will try to give you the position of the cursor in the TgtOnCellDrawEvent. It will be available in the next update. You can send us a mail (support at gnostice dot com) and we will mail you when the feature or alternate solution is available.